# curl_init() undefined only when script runs from cmd

Tags: php, curl, cmd

`curl_init()` is working fine in my code. But when i execute the script through `cmd` or `PHP`'s `exec()` it failed with me `Fatal Error` of `undefined function curl_init()`.

I double checked the `php_curl` is enabeled. I also checked after restarting my `WAMP`.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like for CLI you use another php.ini

You can check it by running `php -i | grep php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, PHP has a different php.ini file when it is invoked via the command line. You can find out where the php.ini is located by issuing the following command on the command line:

```
$ php -i |grep php\.ini
```